# Div slider not moving correctly with mouse movement

Tags: javascript

I have a slider i made with Javascript but it doesn't move quite correct, it seems to accelerate rather than stay the same speed as the mouse.

I know its a logic error but i can't work out what I am doing wrong, so I am hoping someone can spot the mistake.

The function which deals with the div is this:

```
var calc = function (e) {
    var dif = e.pageX - clickX;
    var parentWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el.parentNode).width);
    var childWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).width);
    var childLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(el).left);
    var left = childLeft + dif;

    if (left < 0) { left = 0; }
    else if (left > (parentWidth-childWidth)) { left = (parentWidth-childWidth); }

    el.style.left = left + 'px';
};
```

I have provided a **JSFiddle** as well with it in use: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJZKs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very neat widget/implementation.  I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJZKs/3/) to work correctly.

Added

```
    var dif = e.pageX - clickX;
    clickX = e.pageX;// update clickX so next time you calculate the right dif
```

because otherwise it was computing the difference from the very beginning as opposed to from the last time it computed the difference.